# How connect a database informix with python

Tags: python, database, informix

I try to connect to an index database but it tells me the following error:

```
java.lang.java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bson/BSONObject
```

but if I remove the following part of the code it doesn't give me an error

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM  product") 
results = cursor.fetchone()
 
    for row in results:
        print(row)
```

```
import jaydebeapi

jdbc_url = "jdbc:informix-sqli://xxx:3xxx/xxxxx:INFORMIXSERVER=xxxxx;user=xxxx;password=xxxx"
username = "xxxx"
password = "xxxx"

jdbc_driver = "D:\\jdbc-4.50.4.1.jar"

connection = jaydebeapi.connect(
    "com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver", 
    jdbc_url,             
    [username, password],                           
    jdbc_driver                   
)

cursor = connection.cursor()


cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM  product") 
results = cursor.fetchone()

for row in results:
    print(row)

cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

Comment: Sounds like your java environment doesn't have the org.bson jar.  Informix is supposed to have a direct python API, why are you using JDBC anyway?

Comment: As above, if you are using Python better to use the Python Informix driver (IfxPy). 
If you want to use JDBC I suggest to use the latest 4.50.JC10 from Maven (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.informix/jdbc)

Comment: ifxPy is compatible with any version of python ?